# Nginx not serving latest version of JS immediately

Tags: reactjs, nginx, caching, webpack

I am using Nginx for my ReactJs project and used the below configurations to allow browser to cache only images not other files(HTML, JS & CSS). It is working fine for me. But some clients are facing cache issues. Latest html is loaded immediately. But they are getting old JS bundle file. I am using webpack to generate a production bundle. In the html, the bundle code is reflected immediately. Please check the sample HTML & Nginx configuration files below.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <link href="css/main.css?76m85vt7qo00000" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bundle.js?438400c3459a72d63b87"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**NGINX CONF:**

```
http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";


        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

            root /var/www/html;
            index index.html index.htm;

            server_name *.mydomain.com;

            location / {
                add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
                add_header Pragma 'no-cache';
                expires off;

                add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
                if_modified_since off;
                etag off;

                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri /index.html;
            }

            location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ {
                expires 30d;
                log_not_found off;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
            }

            location ~*  \.(js|css)$ {
                expires -1;
                add_header Cache-Control 'no-store';
                add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
            }
        }
}
```

**RESPONSE HEADER:**
[image]

Note: This problem is not happening for all the time for the all users. This problem is resolved automatically by itself after some minutes or hours.

I have cleared the browser cache and tried again. No luck. Failed to get the latest version. How to instruct the Nginx to always serve the latest JS file? I have researched a lot in google but failed to get the reason & solution. Please anyone provide me the way to resolve this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have any active webworker in js?

Comment: yes. I have used serviceWorker [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) in the older releases. Then I have completely removed it in the recent build to resolve the browser cache issue. Still one of my friend reproduced this problem.

Comment: I feel this could still be the problem. You don’t just remove a service-worker, you need to make sure it’a unsubscribe from the browser

Comment: @KerryGougeon I have unregistered service workers like below and It is working fine for me.
`navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function (registrations) {
  for (let registration of registrations) {
   registration.unregister()
  }
 })`

Comment: Have you solv ed this yet? I'm facing the same issue and >I think I have a solution

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

I was led down the "Nginx Cache Webpack Bundle" rabbit hole, only to realize that I had configured nginx to serve the build from an old build directory. So, even though I had the updated bundle and assets compiling correctly, it was still pointing to the old versions of them in the old directory.

It's not the direct solution to the OP's cache invalidation question (looks like unregistering service workers worked there), but an easy sanity-check for anyone else who stumbles up on this